# R: Error in !row.names : invalid argument type

Tags: r

My table k looks like:

```
rsID  
rs6786  
rs798  
rs56,COSM787,COSM687  
rs097,COSM96,COSM90,COSM76
```

I want to have following (I need the word before the first comma):

```
rsID  
rs6786  
rs798  
rs56   
rs097
```

I try to run this code but I have the error: "Error in !row.names : invalid argument type":

```
UPDATE k  
SET rsID = SUBSTRING(rsID, 1, CHARINDEX(',', rsID) - 1)  
WHERE CHARINDEX(',', rsID) > 0
```

Comment: In R you could try `sub(',.*', '', df1$rsID)#[1] "rs6786" "rs798"  "rs56"   "rs097"` 
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `sub`

```
df1$rsID <- sub(',.*', '', df1$rsID)
df1
#   rsID
#1 rs6786
#2  rs798
#3   rs56
#4  rs097
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(rsID = c("rs6786", "rs798",
  "rs56,COSM787,COSM687", 
 "rs097,COSM96,COSM90,COSM76")), .Names = "rsID", 
 class =    "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```